# How can I track and return to sidequests not marked on the map?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I've finished the main story, and most of the sidequests that are marked on the map. However, certain tasks - Maude's bounty hunter missions in particular, but I'm sure there's others - don't show up on the map and are therefore more difficult to track. Also, for one reason or another, it seems I've lost (though I don't recall deleting) all the e-mails and/or text messages related to these quests.

How can I look up my current progress on the quest, and figure out where I need to start again? Can this be done entirely in-game, or will I have to resort to looking up walkthroughs to obtain details that were lost in the texts/e-mails?

Comment: My emails/texts for the 2nd Bail Bond Mission + the 7th step of the epsilon mission (5 cars to steal) disappeared after a while. I had to google for the missions to get back on track :P

Answer (score 4):

For the Bail Bond missions in particular, and probably other missions you may want to track, you can view your progress by signing up with Rockstar Games Social Club and linking the account you're playing with.

In the Social Club page for GTA V, you can view your Career, and a tab under that category labeled Checklist will allow you to see all your progress in various missions.  Maude's missions are under the Hobbies and Pastimes section.

This will only tell you whether you have completed the mission or not, though.  It does not indicate where the target is located, and unfortunately this information does not appear on the Random Events and Strangers map at the bottom of the Checklist page.  I suspect that the map could still be helpful for you to find other sidequests and events you haven't played yet.

As far as I know, there is no way to get back the emails or texts with mission information once they have been deleted (I'm kind of surprised they can be deleted; disappearing spontaneously would definitely be a bug).  Resorting to a guide may be necessary on that front.